# Rewrite all queries to not need the .php extension using a mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I'd like all queries like

```
http://mysite.com/something/otherthing?foo=bar&x=y
```

to be rewritten as

```
http://mysite.com/something/otherthing.php?foo=bar&x=y
```

In other words, just make the .php extension optional, universally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it this way.  Basically, if file doesn't exist, try adding .php to it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now.  Perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: So this says it will perform the RewriteRule if the accessed resource is not a file or directory?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

The idea is to make sure there's a query string (question mark plus stuff) and if so check if the stuff before the question mark has no extension and if so, append .php.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the httpd.conf and what to, you can also put:

```
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
```

in the file as it will force all the paths called to be PHP files. I think this also works with query strings.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
RewriteRule /something/(.+)?(.+) /something/$1.php?$2
```

would probably work.

Comment: You probably need to escape the question mark with a backslash

Comment: I tried that.  I think the query string stuff is just not part of what is matched in a RewriteRule.  You have to do a separate RewriteCond on the query string.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Matches only paths with no extension:

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/+)*[^\.]+)$ $1.php
```

Edit: In my testing, the query string gets passed on automatically. If it doesn't, you can use this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/+)*[^\.]+)$ $1.php?%1
```

Comment: `[QSA, L]` passes query string (`L` means don't process rules after this one).