# hide extension .php in url mod_rewrite

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I have a website in PHP, and I'm trying to hide the extension. I've found a couple of things via Google, but they all seem to be too complicated, or they redirect `index` to `index.php`: like if you write `name.com/contact` it goes to `name.com/contact.php`. I don't want that, I just want:

```
    www.name.com/es/index.php       to be www.name.com/es/inicio
    www.name.com/es/empresa.php     to be www.name.com/es/empresa
    www.name.com/es/productos.php   to be www.name.com/es/productos
    www.name.com/es/clientes.php    to be www.name.com/es/clientes
    www.name.com/es/recetas.php     to be www.name.com/es/recetas
    www.name.com/es/contacto.php    to be www.name.com/es/contacto

    www.name.com/en/index.php       to be www.name.com/en/home
    www.name.com/en/company.php     to be www.name.com/en/company
    www.name.com/en/products.php    to be www.name.com/en/products
    www.name.com/en/clients.php     to be www.name.com/en/clients
    www.name.com/en/recepis.php     to be www.name.com/en/recepis
    www.name.com/en/contact.php     to be www.name.com/en/contact
```

***the `/en/` folder is English version and the `/es/` folder is the Spanish version***

Also the links inside the website, would be also without the extension.

E.g, an image linked to `clientes` would be `clientes` **and not** `clientes.php` **and** if somebody tries to go to `/page.php`, it still works but it redirects to `/page`.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183921/rewrite-all-queries-to-not-need-the-php-extension-using-a-mod-rewrite-rewriterul

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect *.php to clean URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267488/redirect-php-to-clean-url)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The htacces file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

You redirect any php file in the url with the same name withouth the "php".
Then in your php files, you can check to see if the url contains the extension (http://blabla.com/bla**.php**) and redirect the page to the same one withouth the extension.
So, at the beginning of each php file you should call this function :

```
function redirectIfNeeded(){
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if(preg_match("/\.php/$", $url))
        header("Location: ".preg_replace("/\.php/",$url));
}
```

Comment: How does this rewrite `/es/index.php` to `/es/inicio`?

Comment: its ok, im going to change index.php to inicio.php, and then redirect name.com/es/, to name.com/es/inicio

Comment: why is there the dollar sign in the regex in the preg_match?

Comment: `$` in a regex notes the end of the input. ex: `/\.php/$` matches `index.php` but doesn't match `index.php5` (because `php` is not a t the end of the input). more info : http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

Please crate a **.htaccess** file in root directory an use this code!!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Hope!! it would be useful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Please try to provide a description of your solution.