# How can htaccess block php extension if someone types it?

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my htaccess i have this rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

My php extension now is off from my urls.

But the thing is..

If a user types down .php in the end it will load the page.

Is there a way that i can block .php from url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite file extension BUT deny direct access to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623725/rewrite-file-extension-but-deny-direct-access-to-file)

Comment: You whant that if somebody types in "example.com/index.php" he opens "example.com/index" ?

Comment: want to give an error for it, if client types .php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an additional rule with `THE_REQUEST` variable to send forbidden error if client sends direct request for `.php` files:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this

```
RewriteRule ^.*?\.php$ forbidden [F,L]
```

Comment: That will make OP's rule also fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*?\.php$ forbidden [F,L]

</IfModule>
```