# Clean URL with php and apache

Tags: php, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rewrite all queries to not need the .php extension using a mod_rewrite RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183921/rewrite-all-queries-to-not-need-the-php-extension-using-a-mod-rewrite-rewriteru)

I am learning how to create a website, and would like some help.

I have this path in the wamp folder: `C:\wamp\www\Personal_site\Root_fold\index.php` (the main file starts here).

I want to have cleanurls for this file: `C:\wamp\www\Personal_site\Root_fold\Tutorials\C_sharp\C_loginapp.php`, and I want it to show up as `C:\wamp\www\Personal_site\Root_fold\Tutorials\C_sharp\C_loginapp` - the same file, but without the .php on the end.

I also want this to happen to every other file that I have in my website - even the index.php - without repeating the rewritecond for each and every file. How do I do that?

By the way, I am running this locally on my computer - no hosting service or anything like that - and also I am creating the .htaccess file by opening it in notepad and saving the file with the name ".htacess", which means it forces the file to save with the .htacess extension.

Comment: don't use notepad, use [notepad++](http://www.google.com.et/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=notepad%2B%2B&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnotepad-plus-plus.org%2F&ei=flXjTrLiCseg4gTotu27BQ&usg=AFQjCNH20Y39KL3umNlz40yN398ALm0wKg) instead, it is designed for editing code, and can handle various line endings and filetypes without problem.

Comment: Just to clarify your question; `C:\wamp\www\Personal_site\Root_fold\Tutorials\C_sharp\C_loginapp` refers to your local file system, but `http://localhost/Tutorials/C_Sharp/C_loginapp` is your local web URL which I suspect is where you want the rewriting done.

Comment: @mario hi ur almost giving me ideas but so sorry not able to catch them how do i apply it for my website as i have given u the filepath and the file names as well..

Comment: Your filepaths are not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean URLs go beyond just hiding the `.php` extension. It also needs to incorporate query parameters, so that instead of `/article?title=foobar` it looks like `/article/foobar`.

This problem was solved over and over and over again. Please don't participate in the PHP community's pervasive [Not invented here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) syndrome and use one of the [existing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) [solutions](http://silex.sensiolabs.org) [available](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html). It will make you a better programmer in general, because today's programming is about artfully combining existing components with your unique domain logic instead of writing everything from scratch.

**UPDATE**

Since you are just starting, it might be hard for you to start using a full-blown framework like [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) — but I suggest to use it when you'll be more comfortable with PHP.

For now, the [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) micro-framework might be a good start for you. It's very easy to start with. As a simple example, here is your `index.php` file:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
}); 

$app->run();
```

And this is your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is a complete app written in Silex. When you go to `<yourhost>/hello/JackyBoi` it will respond with `Hello JackyBoi`.

You can do more advanced stuff with Silex — details are in the docs. When you outgrow it, you can naturally graduate to its bigger brother Symfony2.

Comment: ok officially this is confusing can u just give me a code on what to put in the .htacess file?

Comment: Updated the answer in response to your request for examples.

Comment: hey tks man but was wondering how to add the silex.phar file i have downloaded it but where do i put it ?

Comment: Put it into the same folder with `index.php` and `.htaccess` — this is an easy way to start. As soon as you manage to run this app, you can experiment by moving the `silex.phar` file off the document root and updating the `require_once` statement accordingly — your app will be safer this way.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htacceess:

```
 Options +MultiViews
```

Remove all the rewriterules. Then you can use URLs (not filenames!!) without the `.php` extension.

Comment: Still not able to hide the extension .php wat am i doing wrong? ijust tried the Options -Indexes and this is working as it is not showing me the files in the folder

Comment: Requires mod_negotiate. Also nobody can tell what you are doing wrong, unless you concretise your steps.

Comment: ok then i will tell you exactly what i am doing better i made a screencast so that you can see for yourself this is the youtube link- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb0hV342wnE  but i will show u in the writing as well first i created a .htacess file in my rootfolder where my my index.php is and then i have folder called Tutorials and inside a subfolder called Csharp and inside the .php file. In the .htacess which I have it in the rootfolder i put ur line Options +MultiViews and refreshed my .php page but no hiding of the extension

Comment: Neither option will hide extensions for you. It rewrites only **incoming** requests, not outgoing pages. Adapt your links yourself.