# URL Routing with get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to shorten my URL from:

```
localhost/group.php?(GET_REQUEST_VARIABLE_HERE)
```

to

```
localhost/(GET_REQUEST_VARIABLE-VALUE)
```

essentially it would be like this:

```
localhost/group.php?id=7 TO localhost/7
```

I am using PHP and I'm guessing I need an htaccess file.

Comment: I recommend you read about htaccess and mod_rewrite before asking I could recommend you this guide: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked on this site a lot. E.g. [Rewrite all queries to not need the .php extension using a mod_rewrite RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183921/rewrite-all-queries-to-not-need-the-php-extension-using-a-mod-rewrite-rewriteru)

But to answer your question. If you are using the Apache web server you are correct, you need a .htaccess file. This would probably work sufficiently:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will reroute all your requests that are not actual files to your index.php file. Of course this will require you to implement some routing logic in your index file, to determine what page you really want to access, but that is how you achieve pretty urls.

Comment: What's mod_rewrite.c?

Comment: mod_rewrite.c is a module that you can include in apache to enable url rewriting; what you're trying to do is exactly that, you want to take one url (localhost/user/2) and redirect it to index.php (unless you have a file called localhost/user/2, but that would be just silly).

Comment: could you be more specific, "it did not work for me" isn't helpful at all. Is there some error being thrown anywhere, or what kind of problem do you have.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for you in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ group.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This did not work for me either. When I try going to localhost/(Enter_ID_Here) it is saying page not found

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered hundreds of times I already recommended you to read more about it in a comment to your post.

By the way this .htaccess should be ok

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ group.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Remember to:

1. Check you have mod_rewrite enabled in apache in order to an .htaccess to work.
2. Restart apache after installing modules

To install the apache rewrite module use the command `a2enmod rewrite`.
To restart apache use `sudo service apache2 restart`

And please read http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite first you do not want to configure a htaccess wrong is one of the worst things on a web developer life :O :( ..